# Trying to obtain data whose status are active in database and it should be displayed in dropdown list

Tags: codeigniter

I'm trying to give a dropdown list in view, but that should be from database.

This is my Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('welcome_message');
}

public function subject()
{
    $this->load->view('sub');

}
```

In view simple dropdown list i have given,Each subject is having different id, which I have given in value of the option tag.
And only the subjects which statuses are active should be listed.
How to do that???

Comment: Show your `view page` code ,`query in model` to fetch drop down data , `database table` for drop down list

Comment: This is view: <select>
  <option value="1">Maths</option>
  <option value="3">Science</option>
  <option value="5">Hindi</option>
  
 </select>

Comment: do you have any table(database table) for your drop down?

Comment: Yea I have created a table which consits of id,status and subject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

load your `model` in your controller assuming as`adminmodel`
Change your controller to

```
public function subject()
{
   $this->load->model('adminmodel');
   $data['info']=$this->adminmodel->get_dropdown();
    $this->load->view('sub', $data);

}
```

In your model add get_dropdown() function

```
    public function get_dropdown()
            {
          $this->db->where('status', 'active');             
          $query=$this->db->get('tablename');
                return $query->result_array();

            }
```

In your view page

```
 <select> 
<?php foreach($info as $info){ ?>
<option value="<?php echo $info['id']; ?>"><?php echo $info['subject']; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Im getting this error: Message: Undefined property: Controller::$db

Filename: core/Model.php

Comment: have changed the tablename with your corresponding table

Comment: Make sure to autoload model on `application/config/autoload.php` at line 56.  `$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');`

Comment: It is coming, But in database table I have a column called status which consists of active and inactive values, I want only active subjects to be listed. Please help me.

Comment: add this in your query `$this->db->where('status', 'active'); ` i have edited my answer. mark as right answer if it works for you